# I'm finding it hard to understand how functions work. Would someome mind explaining them?

Tags: python, function, beautifulsoup, pytube

Please excuse the extra modulus. I've taken a small part of my code out to convert it into functions to make my code less messy. However I'm finding it really hard to understand how I put values in and take them out to print or do things with. See the code I'm using below. **VideoURL** would be replaced with a url of a video.

`

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from pytube import YouTube
from pytube import Channel


channelURL = "videoURL"
YouTubeDomain = "https://www.youtube.com/channel/"


def BeautifulSoup(Link):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(Link, cookies={'CONSENT': 'YES+1'}).text, "html.parser")
    data = re.search(r"var ytInitialData = ({.*});", str(soup.prettify())).group(1)
    json_data = json.loads(data)

    channel_id   = json_data["header"]["c4TabbedHeaderRenderer"]["channelId"]
    channel_name = json_data["header"]["c4TabbedHeaderRenderer"]["title"]
    channel_logo = json_data["header"]["c4TabbedHeaderRenderer"]["avatar"]["thumbnails"][2]["url"]
    channel_id_link = YouTubeDomain+channel_id
    print("Channel ID: "+channel_id)
    print("Channel Name: "+channel_name)
    print("Channel Logo: "+channel_logo)
    print("Channel ID: "+channel_id_link)

    
def vVersion(*arg):
    YTV = YouTube(channelURL)
    channel_id = YTV.channel_id
    channel_id_link = YTV.channel_url

    c = Channel(channel_id_link)
    channel_name =c.channel_name
    return channel_id_link, channelURL

channel_id_link, video = vVersion()
print(channel_id_link)
Link = channel_id_link
print(Link)
Test = print(BeautifulSoup(Link))
Test()
```

So the errors I keep getting are about having too many or too few args for the functions .

Here's the current error:
`

```
BeautifulSoup() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
  File "C:\Users\Admin\test\video1.py", line 26, in BeautifulSoup
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(Link, cookies={'CONSENT': 'YES+1'}).text, "html.parser")
  File "C:\Users\Admin\test\video1.py", line 53, in <module>
    Test = print(BeautifulSoup(Link))
```

`I know I'm missing something very simple.

Any help would be welcome, thank you!
`

I have tried to take the code out of my main code to isolate the issue.

I was expecting to gain a perspective on the issue.

I tried the following code to train myself on functions but it didn't really help me fix the issue I'm having with my project.

```
def test():
    name = (input("Enter your name?"))
    favNumber = (input("Please enter your best number?"))
    return name, favNumber

name, favNumber = test()
print(name)
print(float(favNumber))
```

Comment: It's because you have named your function "BeautifulSoup". You should never name your function as same as your module's name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you have named your function as `BeautifulSoup` which is as same as the name of the function from the library you have imported. Instead of using the function `BeautifulSoup` from `bs4`, it is now running the code you have defined which takes only one argument. So give your function another name.